# How to implement "text selection" (like default browser behavior on plain HTML text), for SVG paths as text?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, typography

I have [this Hebrew rendering example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76020813/how-can-i-get-this-text-layout-algorithm-to-properly-scale-the-text-to-font-siz), which is a special implementation of text as SVG paths, because we need to stretch each glyph in some cases at specific spots, to justify the text and make it flush on the sides. **Code is duplicated below in this post for posterity.**

Is it possible to somehow implement "text selection" like you get for free in the browser on regular HTML text? These are SVG `path`s rendering the text, so how can you think of a way to make it so they can (1) highlight over the SVG paths representing the text, and (2) "copy" the highlighted text?

This image shows regular HTML text (the bottom) and SVG path text (the top), one is selectable, the other is not.

[image]

I know about the [text selection and range browser API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection), but not sure that would be appropriate here. What do you think would be a desired solution? You don't need to implement it, as that might be complex, but perhaps you could explain the techinque that should be used to implement selection functionality on these SVG paths so that it feels like native HTML selection. That is all I really am looking for, a high level description of what an implementation should do.

So here is the code, notice you can't highlight the Hebrew text because it is SVG paths.

```js
// this is the main drawing function,
// called at the very end.
function draw() {
  const words = []

  chapter.verses.forEach(v => {
    words.push(
      ...String(v.value[0].text)
        .split(/\s+/)
        .map(word => {
          return [...word].filter(c => ALPHABET.includes(c)).join("")
        })
    )
  })

  const lines16 = render(words, 16)
  lines16.forEach(line => document.querySelector(".container-16")?.appendChild(line))
  
  const lines32 = render(words, 32)
  lines32.forEach(line => document.querySelector(".container-32")?.appendChild(line))
}

const chapter = {
  verses: [
    {
      index: 0,
      type: "verse",
      value: [
        {
          language: "hebrew",
          script: "hebrew",
          text: "ויהיו חיי שרה מאה שנה ועשרים שנה ושבע שנים שני חיי שרה׃"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      index: 1,
      type: "verse",
      value: [
        {
          language: "hebrew",
          script: "hebrew",
          text:
            "ותמת שרה בקרית ארבע הוא חברון בארץ כנען ויבא אברהם לספד לשרה ולבכתה׃"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

let measurer

function addToMeasurer(el) {
  initializeMeasurer()

  if (!measurer) {
    return
  }

  measurer.appendChild(el)
}

function initializeMeasurer() {
  if (measurer) {
    return
  }

  measurer = document.createElement("span")
  measurer.setAttribute("id", "measurer")

  measurer.style.position = "absolute"
  measurer.style.height = "auto"
  measurer.style.width = "auto"
  measurer.style.whiteSpace = "nowrap"
  document.body.appendChild(measurer)
}

function removeFromMeasurer(el) {
  if (!measurer) {
    return
  }

  el.parentNode?.removeChild(el)
}

function setMeasurerFont({ family, size }) {
  if (!measurer) {
    return
  }

  if (family) {
    measurer.style.fontFamily = family
  }

  if (size) {
    measurer.style.fontSize = typeof size === "number" ? `${size}px` : size
  }
}

const GLYPHS = {
  // horiz-adv-x="646"
  "\u05c6": `M62.5 425q7.5 70 40 139.5t72.5 151t110 223.5l-184 1q30 211 0 418l148 -1q3 40 -8 75.5t-21.5 62.5t-40.5 89h-23l6 60h74l3 -60h-23q27 -37 37.5 -63.5t22 -62.5t19.5 -101l35 7l-3 274h-23l4 60h76l4 -60h-23l4 -280h25q13 76 26.5 109t17 50t36.5 55h-24l4 70h73 l6 -70h-23q-25 -57 -34.5 -85.5t-20 -57.5t-17.5 -75l160 -1q-20 -241 -8 -425l-204 10q-70 -154 -83.5 -198t-33.5 -128t-13 -138t53 -54h321q1 -210 32 -420h-303q-223 30 -263.5 119t-40.5 162.5t7.5 143.5z`,
  א: `M1110 0q-118 13 -157 59.5t-156 191.5l-521 541q-16 -93 -6 -277v-187q306 5 306 -98l-10 -84q-26 -73 -42 -104.5t-84 -181.5l-50 -14q59 124 18 144l-118 20q-71 1 -82 -67l-22 6l-2 67v45l1 78q0 35 10.5 146.5t0.5 199.5q-5 164 19 367l-155 187l33 426l-16 129
l36 -10l32 -152q52 -24 573 -628q101 87 159 168l-248 258l172 247l15 127l24 -4l10 -151l13 -19q199 -164 189 -278q-10 -140 -51 -161l-224 -243l152 -168l173 -150l50 83l19 -15l-35 -98z`,
  ב: (p = 0) => `
M ${1242 + p} 421
L ${1218 + p} 0
H 69
L 83 211
L 77 422
L ${1032 + p} 424
L ${1015 + p} 906
L 67 908
L 69 1352
L 49 1464
L 86 1454
L 117 1354
L 179 1355
L 178 1624
H 153
V 1693
L 225 1694
V 1624
H 208
L 223 1358
H ${1113 + p}
L ${1143 + p} 1428
H ${1178 + p}
L ${1153 + p} 1358
L ${1148 + p} 936
L ${1142 + p} 420
L ${1202 + p} 421
L ${1237 + p} 511
L ${1270 + p} 501
Z
`,
  ג: `M686 248q0 -248 -29 -248q-20 0 -22 27q-5 47 -63 232q-54 169 -102 389q-50 116 -91 229l-22 71l-262 -4q22 205 4 409l157 1q-8 73 -18 102.5t-17 53.5t-34 74h-25l5 50h74l4 -50h-27q36 -56 40 -79.5t15 -53.5t20 -93h39l-2 280h-24l6 60h68l8 -60h-24l6 -280h37
q16 76 27.5 101.5t22 49.5t40.5 69h-24l6 60h66l3 -60h-17q-29 -50 -43.5 -77.5t-24.5 -53.5t-19 -89h172q-30 -203 0 -407l-172 -3l60 -127q20 -59 57.5 -113.5t79.5 -145.5q45 -223 45 -314zM497 550q-13 -404 -68 -459.5t-150 -86.5l-104 -1l-170 -3q40 224 60 488
q65 -64 155 -58t179 57z`,
  ד: (p = 0) => `
M ${1255 + p} 935
L ${1117 + p} 928
L ${1156 + p} 613
L ${1230 + p} 356
Q ${1265 + p} 142 ${1209 + p} 71
T ${1137 + p} 0
Q ${1090 + p} 0 ${1090 + p} 43
L ${1007 + p} 642
L ${988 + p} 930
L 109 926
Q 136 1102 116 1353
L 106 1444
H 134
L 159 1354
L 240 1359
L 242 1624
H 220
V 1684
L 300 1683
V 1622
L 274 1624
L 281 1358
H ${1225 + p}
L ${1260 + p} 1458
L ${1292 + p} 1448
L ${1274 + p} 1358
Q ${1230 + p} 1178 ${1255 + p} 935
Z
`,
  ה: (p = 0) => `
M ${1260 + p} 1168
L ${1257 + p} 930
L ${1127 + p} 928
L ${1185 + p} 645
Q ${1242 + p} 393 ${1214 + p} 164
Q ${1215 + p} 142 ${1159 + p} 71
T ${1087 + p} 0
Q ${1050 + p} 0 ${1050 + p} 43
Q ${1050 + p} 219 ${987 + p} 926
L 128 930
L 126 1353
L 106 1454
H 144
L 172 1354
H 249
L 247 1602
L 226 1604
V 1680
L 313 1690
L 315 1604
H 290
L 291 1358
L ${1211 + p} 1356
L ${1250 + p} 1458
H ${1292 + p}
L ${1254 + p} 1358
Z
M 578 327
L 486 0
Q 317 20 237 73
T 138 331
Q 140 400 151 439
T 177 541.5
A 451.24 451.24 0 0 0 223 660
L 250 658
Q 242 587 246.5 548.5
T 282.5 457
Q 314 404 578 327
Z
`,
  ו: `M567 164q0 -23 -36.5 -93.5t-62.5 -70.5q-44 0 -44 43l9 768q0 117 -87 117l-240 -6q2 255 -23 426l282 10q200 0 200 -297l11 -448q21 -205 -9 -449z`,
  ז: `M637 941l-218 -3q41 -101 87 -280.5t36 -278.5q0 -113 -24 -249q-23 -130 -53 -130q-52 0 -52 23q0 -2 -3.5 49t-3.5 88q0 21 -30 177t-40 312q-10 73 -5 134t-11 161l-217 -1q7 184 -11 416l157 5q2 64 -3.5 90t-25.5 68.5t-40 71.5h-12l-2 60h67l4 -60h-16
q19 -26 34 -64.5t23.5 -70t16.5 -96.5l49 -2l10 288h-14l3 50h63l-4 -50h-14l3 -291l49 1q14 60 29.5 105.5t25 65t44.5 69.5h-15l5 60h55l2 -60l-17 1q-29 -55 -40 -72.5t-26 -65.5t-15 -102h149q-10 -283 0 -419z`,
  ח: (p = 0) => `
M1279 928h-178q47 -387 48.5 -476t-11.5 -199.5t-54 -181.5t-57 -71q-57 0 -57 43q-30 176 -26.5 353.5t59.5 531.5h-177l-17 296l-118 232l-78 -198l-12 -326l-193 -5q42 -341 37 -479.5t-11.5 -293t-67.5 -154.5q-39 0 -39 41q-73 258 -71.5 415.5t44.5 471.5l-186 4
q12 190 -4 424q6 118 4 118h20l40 -116l438 6l99 252l111 -258h462q-14 -160 -5 -430z
`,
  ט: `M1163.5 314.5q-109.5 -254.5 -293.5 -314.5h-235h-339l-64 956l-117 3q22 186 -6 393l125 2q-5 69 -9 98.5t-10 62.5t-35 79h-14l-1 60h64l3 -60h-17q29 -45 33 -73.5t9 -61.5t4 -105l40 -1l2 290l-14 -1l-4 60h65l3 -60h-17l2 -290h28q4 84 7.5 100t8.5 47.5t35 90.5
l-18 -1l-3 67l72 4l-1 -70l-14 -1q-26 -55 -31 -78t-11.5 -59.5t-0.5 -99.5h97q-5 -179 7 -399l-163 -4l49 -539l501 -20q147 0 185 90.5t53 205t-54 159.5q-19 95 -152 110t-241 -32q-44 -38 -57 -70t-49 -37l64 484q86 56 254.5 48t228 -100.5t91 -186.5t41.5 -166.5
t9 -199t-110.5 -381z`,
  י: `M580 1031q0 -147 -80 -392q-51 -191 -112 -191q-28 0 -33 15v32q50 146 65.5 247.5t15.5 98.5q0 85 -136 87h-148l-25 -108l-16 2q-9 250 -9 371l-10 401h30l40 -236h149q267 0 269 -327z`,
  ך: `M1250 1158q5 -227 5 -230l32 -1513l-97 13q-79 1366 -146 1433t-185 67h-684q21 194 11 310t-12 116l941 4q59 0 97 -47t38 -153z`,
  כ: `M1198 678q0 -392 -168 -544q-148 -134 -500 -134h-501q22 210 4 420h669q171 0 285 54q78 118 78 214q0 240 -514 240t-514 4q22 210 12 316t-13 106l699 4q246 0 352 -150q111 -156 111 -530z`,
  ל: (p = 0) => `
M ${1228 + p} 782
Q ${1228 + p} 560 ${1183.5 + p} 410.5
T ${1083.5 + p} 172
Q ${1028 + p} 83 ${953 + p} 41
T ${778 + p} -5
L ${530 + p} 7
Q ${549 + p} 187 ${536 + p} 393
L ${887 + p} 401
Q ${984 + p} 407 ${1027.5 + p} 441
T ${1086.5 + p} 540.5
Q ${1102 + p} 606 ${1106 + p} 701
Q ${1098 + p} 788 ${1083 + p} 818
T ${1025 + p} 887
Q ${982 + p} 926 ${889 + p} 926
L 264 936
Q 255 1020 255 1077.5
T 225 1396
L 213 1786
Q 213 1821 145 1818
L 101 1729
H 95
Q 113 1910 99 2039
L 90 2136
L 98 2142
L 128 2043
H 152
L 189 2163
H 199
L 202 2045
L 269 2032
Q 305 2023 311 2012
Q 325 1997 325 1941
A 827.14 827.14 0 0 0 320 1854
L 360 1359
L ${671 + p} 1358
Q ${833 + p} 1358 ${943 + p} 1294.5
T ${1116.5 + p} 1114
Q ${1180 + p} 997 ${1228 + p} 782
Z
`,
  ם: `M378 924l8 -504h707l-7 397q-2 69 -39 92q-30 19 -106 19zM1231 0h-994l-11 928q-83 3 -101 7q14 190 4 304.5t-13 114.5l836 4q279 0 279 -297v-1061z`,
  מ: `M1103 0h-585l-5 420h514q37 83 37 151q30 146 -63 252.5t-288 106.5q-208 30 -227 -110t-39 -277q0 -6 -21.5 -85t-41.5 -139q-50 -197 -179 -319q-39 0 -39 41l195 859q5 45 -1.5 63t-50.5 46l-196 57q29 182 44 418q145 -18 282 -45q71 -24 96 -61t40 -101.5t10 -119.5
q-71 -189 5 -146q65 102 80 141t21.5 108t6.5 162l153 -4q43 0 129 -44q89 -50 136 -123q113 -153 113 -447q-1 -75 -1 -184.5t-125 -619.5z`,
  ן: `M567 905l-192 5q20 -151 35 -246l50 -479q-6 -269 -12.5 -444.5t-28 -245.5t-37.5 -70q-44 0 -44 43q-80 847 -75 1055t-11 389l-172 1q13 216 -1 426l139 3q2 49 -2 74t-9 48.5t-29 87.5h-26l3 70h79l-2 -69l-25 -1q33 -63 36.5 -84.5t7.5 -49.5t13 -79l31 -2l12 281
h-25l3 80l80 -1l-2 -78h-24l1 -279l32 1q11 60 15 78t13.5 49.5t43.5 83.5h-25v71h81l3 -70h-27q-29 -52 -38 -75t-17.5 -50.5t-8.5 -83.5l157 1q-12 -203 -2 -440z`,
  נ: `M621.5 119q-40.5 -89 -263.5 -119h-303q31 210 32 420h321q46 0 53 54t-13 138t-33.5 128t-83.5 198l-204 -10q12 184 -8 425l160 1q-7 46 -17.5 75t-20 57.5t-34.5 85.5h-23l6 70h73l4 -70h-24q33 -38 36.5 -55t17 -50t26.5 -109h25l4 280h-23l4 60h76l4 -60h-23
l-3 -274l35 -7q8 65 19.5 101t22 62.5t37.5 63.5h-23l3 60h74l6 -60h-23q-30 -62 -40.5 -89t-21.5 -62.5t-8 -75.5l148 1q-30 -207 0 -418l-184 -1q70 -142 110 -223.5t72.5 -151t40 -139.5t7.5 -143.5t-40.5 -162.5z`,
  ס: `M513 928l-125 -5q9 -149 9 -173q-10 -174 63 -260q97 -81 113 -81h119q172 0 213 35q100 52 125 108t35 126q0 156 -54 183q-83 77 -289 67h-209zM1198 678q0 -312 -127 -495q-145 -210 -444 -210q-105 0 -232 172q-114 152 -144 418q0 293 -8 365l-139 4q32 210 17 316
t-17 106l621 4q238 0 357 -178q116 -174 116 -502z`,
  ע: `M1150 1083q0 -66 -221 -583q-35 -67 -84 -146.5t-96 -146.5t-122.5 -147t-558.5 -170l15 174l-15 174l320 63l-144 631l-143 2q24 196 4 429l144 -1q-20 48 -24 76t-8 59.5t-42 84.5h-15l2 50h68l-1 -50h-16q31 -24 34.5 -54.5t12.5 -54.5t13 -108l32 -2l5 270l-16 1
l4 50l62 -2l-2 -50l-19 -2l-1 -270l25 4q10 104 25 129.5t18 45.5t22 44h-16l3 53l68 -1l-2 -52h-16q-22 -43 -30.5 -69.5t-21.5 -70t-16 -76.5l116 -2q-13 -206 4 -428l-190 -6l145 -609q267 106 323.5 192t160.5 296q9 37 -26 62l-223 120q113 188 159 391l87 -56
q197 -73 197 -244z`,
  ף: `M1193 -655q-55 0 -105 43l-30 1503q0 37 -38 37h-782l1 -342l405 -5q5 -41 5 -97q0 -85 -6 -155l-47 -4h-262q-37 4 -64.5 14t-39 28.5t-41.5 65.5t-62 330v584l-21 137l32 10l45 -146l93 10h655q288 0 289 -297z`,
  פ: `M740 449q-447 -35 -515.5 30.5t-93.5 141t-42 212t-17 191.5l4 319l-3 141l22 30l35 -166l914 10l49 -156q72 -135 92 -522l-10 -477q-75 -196 -138 -259.5t-127 -78.5t-303 -55l-557 -10l18 440h899l75 1l13 201l-98 10q-10 319 -11 513l-771 3l1 -202l555 -5
q-5 -102 9 -312z`,
  ץ: `M563 945l-172 -5q40 -181 97 -574q157 88 225 184t103 161.5t17.5 142t-183.5 183.5q84 149 150 354l5 139l21 -3l24 -141l150 -96q91 -68 106 -111.5t16.5 -74t-16.5 -82.5q-53 -142 -79.5 -186.5t-117.5 -190t-169 -213t-239 -152.5l37 -316q3 -204 -5 -331
t-28.5 -197.5t-76.5 -70.5q-17 0 -68 435l-72 1140l-179 -1q13 232 6 410l149 3q7 70 0 100t-13.5 59.5t-40.5 79.5l-16 1v60l70 -1l-1 -59h-16q35 -49 42.5 -78.5t10 -59t7.5 -98.5l32 1l8 290h-13l1 49h69l-2 -49h-17l-2 -290l30 -1q7 64 14.5 94.5t16.5 60.5t33 75l-16 1
l-1 60h76l-1 -60l-19 -1q-26 -48 -33.5 -77t-15.5 -57.5t-13 -96.5h111q-12 -173 -2 -410z`,
  צ: `M1134 288q0 -61 -34 -135.5t-212 -154.5h-788q33 215 25 420h667l-497 518h-174q2 204 -9 426h141q-3 62 -14 93.5t-17.5 62.5t-28.5 93l-20 -3l2 51l75 6l-2 -50l-18 -3q24 -61 31 -92t14 -61.5t11 -92.5l29 -2l7 300h-15l1 42l67 2l-4 -44h-16l4 -300l29 2
q12 73 18.5 104t12.5 62.5t29 83.5h-17l2 46l63 1v-47h-17q-20 -52 -24.5 -83.5t-9.5 -62.5t-15 -104h103q-20 -205 2 -428l-105 -1l331 -233q138 143 139.5 166.5t-2.5 42.5t-128 147q150 189 214 308l31 153l4 27l14 -23l5 -152q141 -121 158.5 -166t13.5 -72.5t-9 -66
t-66.5 -135.5t-296.5 -287q178 -147 246 -209q50 -52 50 -149z`,
  ק: `M1179 628q-5 -130 -13 -307.5t-150 -250t-224 -71.5h-99l-2 417h110l153 8q92 28 103 84.5t11 146.5q0 180 -38.5 211.5t-80 46.5t-144.5 15l-708 4q22 190 2 422h107l1 267l-32 1l1 69l96 -1l-1 -68h-33l5 -264h607q165 0 237 -101q77 -135 87 -317t5 -312zM477 262
h-140q34 -347 60.5 -462t19.5 -475h-55q-159 600 -113 934l-98 10l2 322h324v-329z`,
  ר: (p = 0) => `
M ${1232 + p} 30
L ${1190 + p} 0
L ${1147 + p} 30
L ${1055 + p} 811
Q ${1055 + p} 928 ${876 + p} 928
H 244
Q 135 928 104 932
Q 126 1122 116 1238
T 104 1354
L ${960 + p} 1358
Q ${1238 + p} 1358 ${1239 + p} 1061
Z
`,
  ש: `M1321 1095q20 -103 -67 -346q-36 -31 -108.5 -173t-153.5 -265t-223.5 -182t-469.5 -129l-132 938l-101 2q12 104 8 421l97 1q-14 66 -21 93.5t-14.5 55.5t-21.5 73h-17v50h72l2 -49l-17 -1q14 -45 21 -73t14 -55.5t21 -93.5l30 -3l5 280l-20 -2l2 51l58 1l1 -50h-19
l3 -280l30 2q14 68 21.5 96.5t14.5 57.5t21 76h-18l1 48l71 2l2 -48l-18 -1q-14 -48 -20.5 -76.5t-13 -57.5t-19.5 -96h97l3 -297v-122l-159 -6l85 -387q86 30 157 95.5t124.5 135.5t60 98t3.5 30.5t-15 17t-115 36.5l-49 10q28 162 1 379l4 142l12 10l34 -148
q147 -17 178 -34t67.5 -51.5t56.5 -115t5 -116.5t-33 -83t-61.5 -116.5t-127 -182.5t-271.5 -207l81 -50q438 -85 563.5 175.5t-1.5 308.5l-86 31l27 160l3 247l68 -6q129 -37 157.5 -58.5t72.5 -49.5q37 -57 37 -113z`,
  ת: (p = 0) =>
    `
M ${1255 + p} 194
Q ${1188 + p} 0 ${1173 + p} 0
Q ${1118 + p} 0 ${1118 + p} 43
Q ${1118 + p} 59 ${1075 + p} 400
T ${1032 + p} 811
L ${1022 + p} 928
H 310
Q 294 826 321 732
T 415 495
Q 482 352 472 286
Q 472 135 426 65
Q 383 0 317 0
H 23
L 82 420
H 204
Q 265 444 254 504
T 229 632
Q 215 700 208 765
T 206 939
L 106 943
Q 138 1133 123 1244
T 106 1355
L ${1195 + p} 1359
Q ${1201 + p} 1359 ${1201 + p} 1251
T ${1225 + p} 937
L ${1158 + p} 931
L ${1162 + p} 885
L ${1176 + p} 839
L ${1210 + p} 615
L ${1234 + p} 390
A 1715.2 1715.2 0 0 0 ${1258 + p} 196
Z
`
}

const ALPHABET = [
  "\u05d0",
  "\u05d1",
  "\u05d2",
  "\u05d3",
  "\u05d4",
  "\u05d5",
  "\u05d6",
  "\u05d7",
  "\u05d8",
  "\u05d9",
  "\u05da",
  "\u05db",
  "\u05dc",
  "\u05dd",
  "\u05de",
  "\u05df",
  "\u05e0",
  "\u05e1",
  "\u05e2",
  "\u05e3",
  "\u05e4",
  "\u05e5",
  "\u05e6",
  "\u05e7",
  "\u05e8",
  "\u05e9",
  "\u05ea",
  "\u05c6"
]

const scalePriority = {
  ד: 1,
  ה: 3,
  //'ב': '3.5',
  // ל: 2.5,
  ר: 2,
  ת: 4
}

const X = 2785 / 56
const Y = 3030
const R = X / Y
const LETTER_OFFSET = 1300
const SPACE_OFFSET = 0

function computeLines(words, state) {
  let line = []
  const lines = [line]

  let i = 0

  while (i < words.length) {
    var word = words[i++]
    var list = line.concat(word)
    //if (list.join('').length > 28) {
    //  line = [word.text]
    //  lines.push(line)
    //} else {
    var text = list.join("")
    var size = sumLine(
      text.split("").map(x => {
        return { adjust: 0, symbol: x }
      }),
      state
    )

    if (size > state.maxWidth) {
      line = [word]
      lines.push(line)
    } else {
      line.push(word)
    }
    //}
  }

  return lines
}

function getOffset(glyph, state) {
  const idx = state.alphabet.indexOf(glyph.symbol)
  const bounds = state.bounds[idx]
  const width = bounds.width + glyph.adjust
  return R * width + LETTER_OFFSET
}

function initializeState(fontSize, maxWidth) {
  const alphabet = ALPHABET
  const bounds = measureAllSVGGlyphs(alphabet, fontSize)
  return { alphabet, bounds, fontSize, lineOffset: 0, maxWidth }
}

function formatLine(line, state) {
  const glyphs = line
    .join(" ")
    .split("")
    .map(x => {
      return { adjust: 0, symbol: x }
    })

  if (glyphs[glyphs.length - 1].symbol == " ") {
    glyphs.pop()
  }
  if (glyphs[0].symbol == " ") {
    glyphs.shift()
  }

  let initialSize = Math.ceil(sumLine(glyphs, state))

  const idealWidth = state.maxWidth
  if (initialSize === idealWidth) {
    return glyphs
  }

  let remaining = idealWidth - initialSize

  const stretchA = []
  const stretchB = []
  const stretchC = []
  const stretchD = []

  glyphs.forEach((br, i) => {
    if (!glyphs[i + 1]) {
      if (scalePriority[br.symbol]) {
        // stretchA.push({
        //   glyph: br,
        //   scalePriority: scalePriority[br.symbol],
        // })
      }
    } else if (glyphs[i + 1].symbol == " ") {
      // last symbol
      if (scalePriority[br.symbol]) {
        stretchA.push({
          glyph: br,
          scalePriority: scalePriority[br.symbol]
        })
      }
    } else if (!glyphs[i + 2]) {
      if (scalePriority[br.symbol]) {
        stretchB.push({
          glyph: br,
          scalePriority: scalePriority[br.symbol]
        })
      }
    } else if (glyphs[i + 2].symbol == " ") {
      // last symbol
      if (scalePriority[br.symbol]) {
        stretchB.push({
          glyph: br,
          scalePriority: scalePriority[br.symbol]
        })
      }
    } else if (!glyphs[i + 3]) {
      if (scalePriority[br.symbol]) {
        stretchC.push({
          glyph: br,
          scalePriority: scalePriority[br.symbol]
        })
      }
    } else if (
      glyphs
        .slice(i, i + 3)
        .map(x => x.symbol)
        .join()
        .match(/^\w+$/)
    ) {
      // last symbol
      if (scalePriority[br.symbol]) {
        stretchC.push({
          glyph: br,
          scalePriority: scalePriority[br.symbol]
        })
      }
    } else if (
      glyphs
        .slice(i, i + 4)
        .map(x => x.symbol)
        .join()
        .match(/^\w+$/)
    ) {
      // last symbol
      if (scalePriority[br.symbol]) {
        stretchD.push({
          glyph: br,
          scalePriority: scalePriority[br.symbol]
        })
      }
    } else if (glyphs[i - 1] && glyphs[i - 1].symbol == " ") {
      // last symbol
      if (scalePriority[br.symbol]) {
        stretchD.push({
          glyph: br,
          scalePriority: scalePriority[br.symbol]
        })
      }
    }
  })

  stretchA.sort((a, b) => a.scalePriority - b.scalePriority)
  stretchB.sort((a, b) => a.scalePriority - b.scalePriority)
  stretchC.sort((a, b) => a.scalePriority - b.scalePriority)
  stretchD.sort((a, b) => a.scalePriority - b.scalePriority)

  // var spectrum = [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]

  var spectrum = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]

  var spectrum2 = []

  if (stretchA.length) {
    spectrum2.push(1.0)
  } else {
    spectrum2.push(0.0)
  }
  if (stretchB.length) {
    spectrum2.push(1.0)
  } else {
    spectrum2.push(0.0)
  }
  if (stretchC.length) {
    spectrum2.push(1.0)
  } else {
    spectrum2.push(0.0)
  }
  if (stretchD.length) {
    spectrum2.push(1.0)
  } else {
    spectrum2.push(0.0)
  }

  var totals = splitSpectrum(remaining, spectrum2)

  var adjustmentsA = stretchA.length
    ? splitSpectrum(totals[0], spectrum.slice(0, stretchA.length))
    : []
  var adjustmentsB = stretchB.length
    ? splitSpectrum(totals[1], spectrum.slice(0, stretchB.length))
    : []
  var adjustmentsC = stretchC.length
    ? splitSpectrum(totals[2], spectrum.slice(0, stretchC.length))
    : []
  var adjustmentsD = stretchD.length
    ? splitSpectrum(totals[3], spectrum.slice(0, stretchD.length))
    : []

  while (adjustmentsA.length) {
    var i = getRandomInteger(0, adjustmentsA.length - 1)
    var y = stretchA[i]
    var x = adjustmentsA[i]
    adjustmentsA.splice(i, 1)
    stretchA.splice(i, 1)
    remaining -= x
    y.glyph.adjust = x
  }

  //if (remaining) {
  while (remaining && adjustmentsB.length) {
    var i = getRandomInteger(0, adjustmentsB.length - 1)
    var y = stretchB[i]
    var x = adjustmentsB[i]
    adjustmentsB.splice(i, 1)
    stretchB.splice(i, 1)
    remaining -= x
    y.glyph.adjust = x
  }
  //}

  //if (remaining) {
  while (remaining && adjustmentsC.length) {
    var i = getRandomInteger(0, adjustmentsC.length - 1)
    var y = stretchC[i]
    var x = adjustmentsC[i]
    adjustmentsC.splice(i, 1)
    stretchC.splice(i, 1)
    remaining -= x
    y.glyph.adjust = x
  }
  //}

  //if (remaining) {
  while (remaining && adjustmentsD.length) {
    var i = getRandomInteger(0, adjustmentsD.length - 1)
    var y = stretchD[i]
    var x = adjustmentsD[i]
    adjustmentsD.splice(i, 1)
    stretchD.splice(i, 1)
    remaining -= x
    y.glyph.adjust = x
  }
  //}

  return glyphs
}

function createDynamicPath(index, path, symbol, scale, state) {
  const i = state.alphabet.indexOf(symbol)
  const bounds = state.bounds[i]
  const width = bounds.width

  state.lineOffset += R * width + scale + LETTER_OFFSET

  const transform = `translate(${state.maxWidth -
    state.lineOffset}, 0) scale(${1},-${1})`

  let el = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path")
  el.setAttribute("d", path.replace(/\s+/g, " "))
  el.setAttribute("transform", transform)

  return el
}

function layout(lines, state) {
  const svgs = []

  let I = 0

  lines.forEach((line, i) => {
    state.lineOffset = 0

    const glyphs =
      i != lines.length - 1
        ? formatLine(line, state)
        : line
            .join(" ")
            .split("")
            .map(x => {
              return { adjust: 0, symbol: x }
            })

    const paths = []

    glyphs.forEach(glyph => {
      const g = GLYPHS[glyph.symbol]
      const text = typeof g == "function" ? g(glyph.adjust) : g

      if (glyph.symbol == " " || glyph.symbol == "\u00a0") {
        state.lineOffset += SPACE_OFFSET
      } else {
        paths.push(
          createDynamicPath(I, text, glyph.symbol, glyph.adjust, state)
        )

        I++
      }
    })

    const svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg")
    svg.setAttribute("version", "1.1")
    svg.setAttribute("viewBox", `0 -1900 ${state.maxWidth} 3030`)
    svg.setAttribute("height", `${state.fontSize}`)
    paths.forEach(path => svg.appendChild(path))

    svgs.push(svg)

    state.lineOffset = 0
  })

  return svgs
}

function measureAllSVGGlyphs(glyphs, fontSize) {
  const svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg")
  svg.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 -900 52000 3030")
  svg.setAttribute("version", "1.1")
  svg.setAttribute("height", `${fontSize}`)

  addToMeasurer(svg)

  const measurements = glyphs.map(symbol =>
    measureSVGGlyph(svg, GLYPHS[symbol])
  )

  removeFromMeasurer(svg)

  return measurements
}

function measureSVGGlyph(svg, path) {
  // document.body.style['line-height'] = LINE_HEIGHT + 'px'
  // document.body.style['font-size'] = FONT_SIZE + 'px'

  const el = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path")

  el.setAttribute(
    "d",
    (typeof path == "function" ? path() : path).replace(/\s+/g, " ")
  )

  svg.appendChild(el)

  const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect()

  svg.removeChild(el)

  return rect
  // return svg.querySelector('path').getBoundingClientRect()
}

function render(words, fontSize, maxWidth = 49000) {
  const state = initializeState(fontSize, maxWidth)
  const lines = computeLines(words, state)
  console.log(lines)
  const svgs = layout(lines, state)
  return svgs
}

function getRandomInteger(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min)
  max = Math.floor(max)
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min
}

function sumLine(glyphs, state) {
  let sum = 0
  glyphs.forEach(glyph => {
    if (glyph.symbol == " " || glyph.symbol == "\u00a0") {
      sum += SPACE_OFFSET
    } else {
      sum += getOffset(glyph, state)
    }
  })
  return sum
}

function splitSpectrum(total, spectrum) {
  var smallSum = 0
  spectrum.forEach(x => (smallSum += x))
  var ratios = spectrum.map(x => x / smallSum)
  return ratios.map(x => x * total)
}

draw()
```

```css
.container {
  width: 800px;
}
```

```html
<h2>16 Font Size</h2>
<div class="container container-16"></div>
<h2>32 Font Size</h2>
<div class="container container-32"></div>
```

Comment: Firefox pdf viewer does this by putting hidden text over the top. The viewer is open source.

Comment: @RobertLongson Can you explain in slightly more detail how that would work, like since letters can be stretched and such (and each glyph isn't part of a real font), should I just put a hidden span over each letter and set the width to the `path` width? Hmm, that actually sounds pretty simple if that's what you're saying! What do you mean by "hidden" as well, `visibiliity: hidden`?

Comment: Yes exactly. The hidden text only has to be approximately right.

Comment: Each SVG glyph is positioned with a `transform`, so should I do the same for the spans too in that case? Or does it need to be `display: inline` with flow by the browser? Not sure how absolute spans will function with select.

Comment: I real quick added a `<text transform={transform}>{symbol}</text>` above each `<path>`, but no working functionality with that, hmm...

Comment: Look at what the firefox pdf viewer does.

Comment: @RobertLongson it is kind of a beast codebase, do you know for sure it does this (and perhaps what portion of the code to look at)? I started off a hunch at [text_layer.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/f1b005d7b805e38e731d929b47d78b125765aabe/src/display/text_layer.js), but it doesn't look entirely promising.